# Sort array by both numeric and string keys

Tags: php, arrays

i have tried both ksort and asort but in both cases all always shows at bottom..

but i want to display array of index 'all' at top then numeric fields should be displayed.

Actually i am adding that key manually.

```
    $result['all'] = new stdClass();
    $result['all']->DisciplinaryAction = 'All';
    $result['all']->DisciplinaryActionID = 0;
```

i tried `ksort($result)` and also tried `asort($result)` but in both cases text/string always arranged to bottom..

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DisciplinaryAction] => counseling
            [DisciplinaryActionID] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DisciplinaryAction] => verbal warning
            [DisciplinaryActionID] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DisciplinaryAction] => written warning
            [DisciplinaryActionID] => 3
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DisciplinaryAction] => suspension
            [DisciplinaryActionID] => 4
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DisciplinaryAction] => termination
            [DisciplinaryActionID] => 5
        )

    [all] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DisciplinaryAction] => All
            [DisciplinaryActionID] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Use `uksort`, in your function check if either `$a` or `$b` is `'all'`, if so that's the "smaller" key, otherwise `return $a - $b`.

Answer (score 2):

See [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/476).

The much more sensible way to do this, rather than sorting, is probably just to add the key to the beginning of the array directly:

```
$arr = array_merge(array('all' => new stdClass), $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) or [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to define how this should be handled.

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

EDIT : Here's a comparison function for uksort

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b)
        return 0;
    else if (is_string($a))
        return -1;
    else if (is_string($b))
        return 1;
    else
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: i already have seen usort, uasort but i couldnt figure out how can i make string key to show at top and numeric keys should come after the string key array..

Comment: Edited my post to add the comparison function.

Comment: i am using codeigniter MVC framework. i tried this in controller but still 'all' string key is showing at bottom of array.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour.
Are you sure your array isn't getting sorted after this ?